# I want to read the value of a specific table after user_id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord, discord.js

I want to read the value of a specific table after user_id.

(I use discord.js v14)
Please see Database picture so that you understand what I mean.

[Databse picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTBMx.png)

Again, I want to get the invite_link value by entering only user_id. Is it even possible?

This is my actually code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { QuickDB } = require("quick.db");
const db2 = new QuickDB();
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

const username = encodeURIComponent('censored');
const password = encodeURIComponent("censored")
const dbname = 'censored';
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
const clusterUrl = "censored";
const authMechanism = "DEFAULT";
const url = `mongodb://${username}:${password}@${clusterUrl}/${username}`;
const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(url);    
const db = client.db(dbname)
client.connect().then(() => {
    console.log("Data: Connected")
}).catch(err => console.error(err)) 


module.exports = { 
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("invite")
        .setDescription("Create invite to download server"),

    execute: async function(interaction, guilds, client, invites) {
        if(interaction instanceof Discord.CommandInteraction) {


const guild = interaction.client.guilds.cache.get(`1013773663910232184`)
if(await db.collection('blacklist').findOne({
    user_id: `${interaction.member.id}`
 })){
    return interaction.reply({ content: `You cant acces to this command! (Error code: 502)`, ephemeral: true})
 }

 const query = { user_id: `${interaction.member.id}` };

const options = {
   projection: { invite_link: 1 } //only return invite link
};

const inviteLink2 = await db.collection('invites').findOne(query, options);

 if(await db.collection('invites').findOne({
    user_id: `${interaction.member.id}`
 })) {
    return interaction.reply({ content: `You always have invite code! This is your invite code: ${inviteLink2}`})
 }

 




        const invitecode = await guild.invites.create('1013793499189100574', { maxAge: 18000, maxUses: 1} );
        db.collection('invites').insertOne({
            user_id: `${interaction.member.id}`,
            invite_link: `${invitecode.url}`
     })
        interaction.reply({ content: `This is your invite: ${invitecode.url} , DO NOT SEND THIS LINK TO ANYONE. Invite expires in 3 minutes.`, ephemeral: true})
        
        


console.log(`${invitecodegetindatabase}`)

        }   

        }
    }
```

THIS IS EDITED CODE

Comment: On a side note, error code 502 is for HTTP requests, and means that the server recieved a bad response from another server, which doesn't really work in your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the document is added to the database correctly

```js
const query = { user_id: `${interaction.member.id}` };

const options = {
   projection: { invite_link: 1 } //only return invite link
};

const inviteLink = await db.collection('invites').findOne(query, options);
console.log(inviteLink);
```

Please read the mongoDB [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/findOne/) thoroughly, it will save lots of time.

Also, since you're adding the document to the database after you make the request it won't exist. Move the query execution to a line after the `insertOne` call.

Comment: Bot reply [object Object] instead of a link. I edited code, see.

Comment: Could you log `JSON.stringify(inviteLink)` to see the object structure so you know what to reference, thanks.

Comment: That will just be the JSON string, you can reference the property by looking at the structure but if you're happy with that I am too